# Get current selected data from qtreeview, not previous

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to read the selected row from a QTreeView. I can however only get the previously selected data.

For instance:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class treeviewExample(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(treeviewExample, self).__init__()
        self.treeview = QTreeView(self)
        self.treemodel = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
        self.treeview.setModel(self.treemodel)
        self.fillData()

        self.treeview.selectionModel().currentRowChanged.connect(self.showSelectedRow)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.treeview, 0, 0, 2, 2)

    def fillData(self):
        item1 = QStandardItem("Item1")
        item2 = QStandardItem("Item2")
        item = (item1, item2)
        for row in item:
            row.setEditable(False)
        self.treemodel.appendRow(item)

        item3 = QStandardItem("Item3")
        item4 = QStandardItem("Item4")
        item = (item3, item4)
        for row in item:
            row.setEditable(False)
        self.treemodel.appendRow(item)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def showSelectedRow(self):
        indexes = self.treeview.selectedIndexes()
        items = []
        for index in indexes:
            items.append(self.treemodel.itemFromIndex(index))
        print([x.text() for x in items])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tree = treeviewExample()
    tree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run this and click first on the top row and afterwards on the bottom row, I get this:

```
[]
['Item1', 'Item2']
```

So I have `['Item3', 'Item4']` selected but the program prints out `['Item1', 'Item1']`. It's always taking my previous selected row, not the current one. Could anyone help me out find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to differentiate between current row and selected row since they are 2 different concepts, for example at the beginning the current row is 0 but there is no selected row. Usually when the user interacts with a row (for example by pressing an item in the row) then first it is established that the pressed row is the current row and an instant later it is indicated that that row is going to be selected.

So if you want to get the selected row then you should use the [`selectionChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) signal:

```
self.treeview.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.showSelectedRow)
```